# How do I make this gradient appear on Chrome on mac and windows?

Tags: css, button, linear-gradients

I have the following css:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 #66BAC0;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(center top , rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 #66BAC0;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#66BAC0', endColorstr='#66BAC0');
```

The -moz-linear-gradient appears on firefox on windows and on mac.  The -webkit one doesn't work on mac and windows.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  I am new to this.

Can someone help me figure it out why it doesn't show up?

Comment: A non-prefixed property or value should *always* be used in addition to prefixed ones.

Comment: Also Firefox supports the new standard unprefixed syntax https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient these days. And so does Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(255,255,255,0.1) 0px, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0px,rgba(255,255,255,0.1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(255,255,255,0.1) 0px,rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(255,255,255,0.1) 0px,rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(255,255,255,0.1) 0px,rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(135deg,  rgba(255,255,255,0.1) 0px,rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1affffff', endColorstr='#1a000000',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
```

Created with [Colorzilla's Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

Comment: Thanks @DACrosby.  But how do I add the background-color within those lines?

Comment: to add color to this just set `background: red;` at the top of the css. that way it will get overwritten if the gradient is supported

Comment: **The comments generated by ColorZilla are misleading. Support for the standard syntax is really much better** - see http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients Safari and mobile WebKit browsers are the only ones that don't support it at this point.